# JSF extending the UIInput does not invoke UPDATE_MODEL on the bean

Tags: jsf

I have created a custom components that extendeds `UIInput` and only overwrites the constructor and `getFamily()` as follows:

```
public HtmlInputDateTime() {
    super();
    setRendererType(RENDERER_TYPE); 
}

@Override
public String getFamily() {
    return COMP_FAMILY;
}
```

The I created the appropriate renderer that only overwrites `getEndTextToRender`. The problem is that although the local value is set and passed among requests (and the value is initially fetched from the model) it never updates the actual backing bean. Any hints why?

Thanks

Using JSF Mojarra 2.2

Answer (score 1):

When creatinf custom components (or any forms in general) it is always a good idea to render `h:messages` to see if there were any validations that failed.

As it turns out component was working just fine but the since the value was a `Date` it failed the conversion. After I added `<f:convertDateTime/>`, it works fine.

Comment: It will be very useful if you post some example code. Regards,

Comment: If the input always requires a date, just call `setConverter(new DateTimeConverter())` in the constructor. By the way, queued but unrendered faces messages are by default logged to server log. Did you pay attention to it as well?